# multiple the queried result from 'msql case'

Tags: mysql

I can get the below output from the following query-

```
SELECT
    (
        CASE
        WHEN ta.Battery = 'HVA' THEN
            'Huawei Valued Battery'
        WHEN ta.Battery = 'HNVA' THEN
            'Canibalized Battery'
        WHEN ta.Battery = 'ZVA' THEN
            'ZTE Valued Battery'
        WHEN ta.Battery = 'ZNVA' THEN
            'ZTE Canibalized Battery'
        END
    ) AS Accessory_category,
    COUNT(ta.Battery) Battery_count
FROM
    tsc_accessory_details_for_repaired_and_qc_pass_phone_list ta
GROUP BY
    ta.Battery,
    ta.Battery
```

[image]

So, I just need to add another column to the result table named as 'cost'. Is there any possibility to get the output by modifying the above mentioned query. 
eg: If the unit cost of 'HVA' is 100, total cost would be 700. If the unit cost of For 'ZVA'  is 200, total cost of 3 items is 600. Kindly suggest me the modification

I require following output-

[image]
thank you
chamath

Answer (score 1):

You can add another `CASE` for this, but you can do this instead:

```
SELECT
    sub.Value AS Accessory_category,
    SUM(COALESCE(ta.UnitCost, sub.UnitCostValue, 0)) AS UnitCost,
    COUNT(ta.Battery) Battery_count
FROM
    tsc_accessory_details_for_repaired_and_qc_pass_phone_list ta
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT 'HVA' Battery, 'Huawei Valued Battery' Value, 100 UnitCose, 700 AS UnitCostValue
    UNION 
    SELECT 'HNVA', 'Canibalized Battery', 200, 600
    UNION 
    SELECT 'ZVA', 'ZTE Valued Battery', 0, 0
    UNION
    SELECT 'ZNVA', 'ZTE Canibalized Battery', 0, 0
) AS sub ON ta.Battery = sub.Battery AND ta.unitCost = sub.UnitCost
GROUP BY
    ta.Battery;
```

So, instead of these case expression, you can list all the values and their matches in a subquery, then join based on it.

Comment: hi thank you but am geeting following error 
[Err] 1222 - The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns

Comment: very same scenario, i check from by knowledge , didnt find anything error as follows [Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'ta.UnitCost' in 'field list' .
 kndly check i have updated my ow requirement , hope you got it. sorry for the inconveniences.

Comment: @ChamathGunasekara What is the unit cost column name exactly in your tables? I am just guessing it.